# jQuery - use button of class to target ONLY next div of class (non-sibling)

Tags: jquery

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkxmhs5v/).

HTML:

```
<div class="block-1">
  <p>
    <a class="more-info">Learn More</a>
  </p>
  <div class="extra-bits">
  <p>
    Yadda Yadda Yadda
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block-2">
  <p>
    <a class="more-info">Learn More</a>
  </p>
  <div class="extra-bits">
    <p>
      Yadda Yadda Yadda
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.more-info').click(function() {
  $('.extra-bits').slideToggle();
});
```

Basically, I need the "learn more" link to target ONLY the next instance of div.extra-bits.

I tried using

```
$(this).next.slideToggle();
```

as well as

```
$(this).nextUntil('.more-info', '.extra-bits').slideToggle();
```

But I can't find anything that does what I want it to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
$('.more-info').click(function() {
    $(this).parent("p").next('.extra-bits').slideToggle();
});
```

get the parent p and then get the next extra-bits

https://jsfiddle.net/dkxmhs5v/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parent()` to up a level in tree and find `next()` .extra-bits near div to execute `slideToggle`

```js
$('.more-info').click(function() {

   $(this).parent().next(".extra-bits").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.extra-bits{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1">
  <p>
    <a class="more-info">Learn More</a>
  </p>
  <div class="extra-bits">
    <p>
      Yadda Yadda Yadda
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block-2">
  <p>
    <a class="more-info">Learn More</a>
  </p>
  <div class="extra-bits">
    <p>
      Yadda Yadda Yadda
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `.find()`. Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkxmhs5v/3/

```
$('.more-info').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div').find('.extra-bits').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can travel up the tree first and find the sibling:

```
$('.more-info').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().siblings('.extra-bits').slideToggle();
});
```